# Why did the mother's dragon attack the village?

Tags: plot-explanation, how-to-train-your-dragon-2

I am confused about a scene in *How To Train Your Dragon 2*.

The dragon of the mother was present in an assault to the village. However, that dragon is member of a nest, where the king is "a good guy", as he is shown to feed his dragons, so it doesn't seem logical to force them assault the village to steal food, so that they can get it back to him. It doesn't make sense, *does it*?

I was wondering if someone could explain this to me or if it is just a plot-hole in the story.

Comment: Ehhhh.... this one, you got me.  Might actually be a plot hole.

Comment: @Radhil I could take that as an answer. ;)

Comment: I'd rather wait and see if a positive or sourced idea shows up, either here or in my head. I like points, I like good answers more.

Comment: I don't remember a scene where Hiccup'a mother's dragon attacked the village - when was it?

Comment: I *think* it was in the start of the movie. That cloudjumper dragon was part of an assault in the village, where it found itself inside the room of the baby Hiccup. Then the mother took a sword in order to protect her baby, but she show that the dragon was actually playing with, so she did nothing! But at that moment, the father rushed in, ready to kill the dragon without second thought..So the dragon stole the mother and lead her back to its nest, where the white-icy king dragon that was killed by Drago's Alpha were located. Does this remind you anything @user568458?

Comment: Ah, yes, got it now. I thought you were saying it attacked the village *while* it was the mother's

Comment: @Radhil 3 days passed...I guess nobody has an answer..so it might be a hole after all!

Comment: Best I can do then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any direct answer to this.

Valka doesn't really detail the years spent away from Berk.  Just that she rescued dragons, learned about them, and stayed in that particular nest (or if you prefer, the Sanctuary).  How she got there is never really explained, but the clearest implication is direct, that Cloudjumper was part of that nest and brought her directly back.

There are a bunch of potential answers that could cover the gap, but they are all speculative:

- The Bewilderbeast's nest could have run short on food, prompting the raid where Valka was taken.  She'd already made a good start in convincing them she wasn't food, and would've just stayed.
- It could have been the Nightmare's raid as were all the others in the first movie, but she may have influenced Cloudjumper into not returning (there being no doubt she'd be eaten if that happened), and found Sanctuary later.
- Cloudjumper may originate from another nest entirely, now that this movie demonstrates there's more than one, which pretty much leaves it open for anything to happen to Valka in the intervening years, as well as any story bit you like from the first two possibilities.

Regardless of your preferred answer (I'd think the first one myself), that would make this a bit of a plot hole.

Comment: I am almost sure it's a **plot hole**! I had thought of your 2nd bullet, but it wouldn't make sense to kidnap her to an "evil nest". The dragon took her to a better place-and that place was the nest we saw in the movie, that's the taste the movie left to me. Thanks. :)